# Deformation Gradient in Fluid Mechanics and the Reynolds Transport Theorem

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differential-geometry, continuum-mechanics

Fluids can be characterized by the fact, that initially neighboring material fluid particles do not remain neighboring during the course of deformation.

The deformation gradient in continuum mechanics is defined via

$$\boldsymbol{F} = \dfrac{\partial \boldsymbol{\varphi}(\boldsymbol{X},t)}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}$$

whereas $\boldsymbol{\varphi}$ is the function of motion and $\boldsymbol{X}$ is the position of a fluid particle in the reference configuration and $t$ is the time.

The Reynolds Transport Theorem (RTT) explains how to compute the material time derivative of a field quantity integrated over volume $\omega(t)$ via
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\omega(t)} \chi  dv 
= 
\int_{\omega(t)} \dfrac{d \chi}{d t} + \chi \text{div}(\boldsymbol{v}) dv
~.
$$

Now my questions concerns the derivation of that formula:

Typically, we make an integral transformation from our spatial volume $\omega(t)$ to the (time) fixed volume $\Omega$ in the reference configuration.
In order to do that we make use of the relation
$$
 dv = \det( \boldsymbol{F} ) dV = J dV~.
$$
How is that allowed? If in fluid mechanics two neighboring particles do not stay neighbors, then the deformation gradient $\boldsymbol{F}$ will be non-continuous (in turbulent flows, this function will have jumps everywhere I suppose). Don't we need a continuous mapping $\boldsymbol{\varphi}(\boldsymbol{X},t)$ in order to apply these differential geometric relations?

P.S.: When we consider solid, I do not have a problem with the RTT since neighboring particles always stay neighbors and $\boldsymbol{\varphi}(\boldsymbol{X},t)$ is a smooth function (although it might be not possible to explicitly state that function).

Comment: *If in fluid mechanics two neighboring particles do not stay neighbors* Do you actually mean "particle" here or do you mean a fluid *parcel* (which would consist of many particles but would be an "element" of a fluid)? In either case, I do not believe I have seen such a requirement before; can you provide a source where it is set to be a requirement?

Comment: @KyleKanos Thanks for your comment. I actually mean fluid particle in the sense, that one particle sits at one particular point in space. The fluid itself is then composed out of a continuous set of points that we can handle in a differential geometric manner (e.g. compute derivatives and so on). The fact, that two neighboring points do not remain neighbors during flow (or deformation how this process is addressed within a continuum mechanical setting) is not a requirement but a fact. Have a look at this very nice video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqBmdZ-BNig

Comment: @KyleKanos A quick search for a source, stating that the mapping $\boldsymbol{\varphi}(\boldsymbol(X),t)$ must be $C^1$ can be found here: https://www.brown.edu/Departments/Engineering/Courses/En221/Notes/Kinematics/Kinematics.htm -> Section 3.2. annotation (iii). 
In my understanding, the smoothness of the mapping between reference and spatial configuration is a crucial requirement in continuum mechanics.

Comment: without sufficient regularity assumptions on your mapping $\varphi$, the integral $\int_{\omega(t)}\chi\,dV$ is not a differentiable function of $t$, and if you make $\varphi$ even worse then the map is not even a continuous function of $t$ so the question doesn’t really make sense. You can try to go down the analysis rabbit hole of considering weak-differentiability, or distributional derivatives (which can take jump discontinuities into account by means of a distributional Dirac delta as derivative), but is this really what you want to consider?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks for your comment! Your point is exactly what my concern is about. In fluid mechanics $\boldsymbol{\varphi}$ is continious in $t$ (one can always follow a single fluid particle) but not in $\boldsymbol{X}$ (in turbulent flow neighboring particles to not remain neighboring and hence $\boldsymbol{\varphi}$ must jump w.r.t. $\boldsymbol{X}$) . So how is it still okay to apply Reynolds transport theorem??

Comment: I don't see how that video relates to anything here. And I don't see where in that document that the neighbors will not remain neighbors after deformation. Can you provide a textbook that makes that exact claim? Or is it simply an inference that *you* have made after reading/watching these?

Comment: @KyleKanos The document states, that $\boldsymbol{\varphi}$ must be smooth. The video shows an experiment that demonstrates  that fluid particles will not remain neighbors (start watching the video after 50s). You can find a source here: https://www.mib.uni-stuttgart.de/cont/downloads/downloads-files/Formelsammlung_TM3_2.pdf (unfortunately it is in german, but the curcial sentence is "Im Zustand der Bewegung bleiben materielle Punkte nicht benachbart."). I try to find another source....but isn't experimental observation proof enough?

Comment: I agree with the constraint of regular fields. Then, what is your question?

Comment: I could not find a book yet, but ChatGPT says:  "In fluid mechanics, a fluid is often defined as a substance that can continuously deform under the application of shear stress. Unlike solids, where neighboring particles tend to maintain their relative positions, in fluids, neighboring particles do not remain fixed in relation to each other during deformation."

I am not sure whether this counts as a source ;-)

Comment: @basics My question is: Why is it allowed to apply the RTT to a field $\chi$, may it be regular or irregular, if the underlying deformation mapping $\boldsymbol{\varphi}(\boldsymbol{X},t)$, needed to transform the integral of interest to the reference configuration, is highly non-continious in $\boldsymbol{X}$?

Comment: You don't need to apply it to proof Reynolds transport theorem. I added an answer below with an external link, where you can find a "proof" without using reference coordinates. I'll sketch the proof in the answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find a (not 100% rigorous) proof of  the Reynolds' transport theorem

https://basics.altervista.org/test/Math/time_derivatives_of_integrals/time_derivatives_of_integrals.html

Let's evaluate the time derivative of a volume integral, using the definition of derivative

\begin{equation}
  \dfrac{d}{dt} \int_{V(t)} f(\mathbf{r}, t) dV = \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \left[ \frac{1}{\Delta t} \left( \int_{V(t+\Delta t)} f(\mathbf{r}, t+\Delta t) dV - \int_{V(t)} f(\mathbf{r}, t) dV \right)  \right]
\end{equation}

Now, let's expand the function $f(\mathbf{r},t+\Delta t)$ in series
\begin{equation}
  f(\mathbf{r}, t + \Delta t) = f(\mathbf{r}, t) + \Delta t \, \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} f(\mathbf{r},t) + o(\Delta t) \ ,
\end{equation}
and the compose the volume $V(t+\Delta t)$ as the (algebraic) sum of the volume $V(t)$ and the difference of the volumes $\Delta V(t,t+\Delta t) = V(t+\Delta t) - V(t)$, so that the first integral reads
\begin{equation}
  \int_{V(t+\Delta t)} = \int_{V(t)} + \int_{\Delta V(t,t+\Delta t)} \ .
\end{equation}

Putting these two manipulations together in the first formula
\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
  \dfrac{d}{dt} \int_{V(t)} f(\mathbf{r}, t) dV & = \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\Delta t} \int_{V(t)} \left(  \Delta t \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}(\mathbf{r}, t) + o(\Delta t)  \right) dV \\ &+ \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{1}{\Delta t} \int_{\Delta V(t,t+\Delta t)}  \left( f(\mathbf{r}, t) + O(\Delta t) \right) dV 
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

1. The first integral on the right-hand side is the volume integral of the time partial derivative
   \begin{equation}
     \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\Delta t} \int_{V(t)} \left(  \Delta t \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}(\mathbf{r}, t+\Delta t) + o(\Delta t) \right) dV = \int_{V(t)} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}
   \end{equation}
2. The second integral is the one that contains the motion of the boundary of the volume. The elementary $\Delta V$ can be computed with the dot product of the elementary displacement and the vector area
   \begin{equation}
    "d \Delta V" = \mathbf{v}_b \Delta t \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} dS \ ,
   \end{equation}
   being $\mathbf{v}_b$ the velocity of the points of the boundary of the volume $V$. Evaluating the limit for $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$ using average value theorem, you can get
   \begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
     \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{1}{\Delta t} \int_{\Delta V(t,t+\Delta t)}  \left( f(\mathbf{r}, t) + O(\Delta t) \right) dV & = \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{1}{\Delta t} \left[ \oint_{\partial V} f(\mathbf{r}, t) \Delta t \mathbf{v}_b(\mathbf{r},t) \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}}(\mathbf{r},t) dS + o(\Delta t) \right] = \\
   & = \oint_{\partial V} f(\mathbf{r}, t) \mathbf{v}_b(\mathbf{r}, t) \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}}(\mathbf{r}, t) dS \ .
   \end{aligned} \end{equation}

Putting everything together, without explicitly writing the independent variables, we've got Reynolds' transport theorem

\begin{equation}
  \dfrac{d}{dt} \int_{V(t)} f = \int_{V(t)} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \oint_{\partial V(t)} f \mathbf{v}_b \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \ .
\end{equation}

**EDIT. Some details about integration: independent variables and domains**
[image]

Comment: After looking over your suggestion, I am not quite sure about your step 2. 
I can relate to the statement, that $\Delta V = \int_{\partial V_t}\Delta t \boldsymbol{v}\cdot \boldsymbol{v} dS $ since the $\Delta $ infront of the $V$ correlates to the $\Delta$ infront of the $t$. But it is not clear to me why is it possible to write $\int_{\Delta V} \dots dV = \int_{\partial V_t} \Delta t \boldsymbol{v} \cdot \boldsymbol{n} dS$. I would rather write $\int_{\Delta V} \dots dV = \int_{  \boldsymbol{v} \cdot \boldsymbol{n} \partial V_t} \dots dV$. But then I am still stuck with the $dV$...

Comment: I've just edited the answer with some details about integration

Comment: If you change the parametrization, aka the independent variables, you need to change the domain of integration to be consistent with the change of variables (since independence is one of the most important principle in physics and math: the results should not depend on an arbitrary choice of variables and parameters)

Comment: awesome. now it is clear. Many thanks again. I wonder why most text books use the transformation back to $V(0)$ and do not provide this more clean derivation.

Comment: My answer is because many books and professors suck. Maybe it's a bit rude, but I haven't found better answers yet. I'm telling you that with an aerospace engineering background with focus on fluid, structure and control dynamics. I lost too much time to make things clear when I was studying, and this is the reason why I started collecting hand-written notes on the website I shared with you

Comment: My suggestion is to reach at least that level: take some question from the main page, add your answer. Someone, hopefully, will upvote your question. Sometimes Physics SE could be quite useful or even entertaining

Comment: @Schneitz the reason why we transform back to $V(0)$ is because that **is** the clean way to proceed. I hope you realize that all the regularity issues in this ‘proof’ (which is actually the typical proof in physics books) have been hidden behind a choice of intuitive pictures. For instance, why does the ‘volume difference’ $\Delta V(t,t+\Delta t)$ have a smooth enough boundary/why can it be foliated by the various boundary slices $\partial V(s)$ for $s\in [t,t+\Delta t]$ (where you should note that some form of the coarea formula **is** being used in order to apply the MVT).

Comment: To me it seems like a lot of the spatial smoothness is just baked deeper into notation, so just because you don’t see the deformation gradient explicitly here, doesn’t mean it/its smoothness isn’t lurking in the background. Of course, the very first sentence does say this is not a 100% rigorous proof, and that’s fine, but you should just note that this answer doesn’t address your regularity concerns. Oh and another reason why this version of proof is not ‘ideal’ (besides lack of rigour) is its difficulty in generalization (manifolds, differential forms etc).

Comment: That's not right, since in this "proof" you only need enough regularity of function $f(\mathbf{r}, t)$ in the physical domain and in the elementary time interval. Obviously, if I perform a Taylor expansion in $t$, that Taylor expansion must have some meaning (i.e. $f$ continuous and differentiable) and $f$ must be a continuous function, so that you can use the average value theorem to evaluate the integral on the surface.

Comment: If you have discontinuities in the function $f$, you could use a regularized version of $f$, or $f$ as a distribution. It's the situation where you perform such a kind of analysis in a inviscid flow with shocks treated as discontinuities. Anyway, nothing here is related to the singularity of the transformation from the reference configuration and the actual physical configuration, from time zero, to the current time: this is such a stronger assumption, that you can't satisfy in general, without splitting your transformation in a subset of time intervals, where the transf is regular

Comment: I’m not referring to regularity of the function $f$ (for which it is obvious some amount of $t$-differentiability, and $x$-measurablity, and by extension, $x$-integrability is needed). I’m talking about the volumes $V(t)$ and how they change with time. Without further $x$-smoothness of $\varphi$, you cannot really say nice things about $V(t)$ (and in particular the volume difference $\Delta V(t,t+\Delta t)$).

Comment: As I told before, in this "proof" you're asking for the regularity of a transformation in a infinitesimal time range, while you're asking for the regularity of a transformation in a finite time range if you use the reference configuration, and this is a much stronger condition

Comment: @peek-a-boo How is the transform back to $V(0)$ clean, if (in fluid mechanics) this spatial to reference configuration transform is not even possible to conduct locally due to a highly non-continuous deformation gradient. As I understand the "back-transformation proof" the RHS of the equation $\int_{V(t)}\dots dV = \int_{V(0)} \dots J dV_0$ is only an idealization which can never be computed and maybe is not well-defined in a general fluid dynamics setting (turbulence is not a super special case but a common one). So how can such a proof be clean? What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: I also found a book that follows the above prove [link](http://library.navoiy-uni.uz/files/leal%20l.%20g.%20-%20advanced%20transport%20phenomena-%20fluid%20mechanics%20and%20convective%20transport%20processes%20(2007)(912s).pdf) page 22 - 23

Comment: @Schneitz $V(0)$ is not necessary. YOu can write $\int_{V(t+\epsilon)}$ in terms of $\int_{V(t)}$ (with a different integrand), and then apply $\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\bigg|_{\epsilon=0}$ to both sides. The cleanness is because of what I said in the end: when dealing with differential forms and manifolds, where this pictorial proof is hard to generalize. A natural ‘philosopy’ in analysis is that dealing with (varying families of) functions (or tensor fields/differential forms) is simpler than dealing with (varying families of) **sets**/surfaces/volumes, because well… functions involve numbers.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks for the insight of why dealing with functions is beneficial. However, I did not quite get your argument. Do you mean to introduce a mapping $\varphi_\epsilon$ that mediates from $V(t)$ to $V(t+\epsilon)$? This mapping might be invertible and good-natured since only two infinitessimal neighboring states are considered. But how does the application of $\frac{d}{d \epsilon}\Bigg|_\epsilon=0$ will then be used in the proof?

Comment: @Schneitz $I’(t)$, or $\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t}I$ is the same thing as $\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\bigg|_{\epsilon=0}I(t+\epsilon)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct, the application of the transport formula requires sufficient regularity of the field. The assumption of regularity may be hard to justify physically especially for turbulent flow.

Consider for example [Onsager's conjecture](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2019/01/08/255b-notes-2-onsagers-conjecture/). Starting from Euler's equation (Navier-Stokes with no friction), you would expect conservation of energy:
$$
E = \frac12\int u^2d^3x
$$
which you can derive from the transport equation assuming regularity. However, for weak solutions this reasoning may fail. Actually, it was proven (see for example [*Energy dissipation without viscosity in ideal hydrodynamics I. Fourier analysis and local energy transfer*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0167278994901171)  by Eyink) that Hölder 1/3-continuity suffices for conservation of energy, so the usual argument involving smoothness can be strengthened to a certain limit. Conversely, you can construct weak solutions that are $\mathcal C^\alpha$ with $\alpha<1/3$ that do not conserve energy (in particular wild solutions which initially start from rest and come back to rest after a finite time). While it is still an open question, the dissipation anomaly could be a result of the weak convergence of Navier-Stokes equation to such an irregular, dissipative solution of Euler.

Similarly, Helmholtz' theorem which states the conservation of circulation, can similarly be proven using the transport theorem. It too can be extended to non-smooth fields, up to $\mathcal C^{1/2}$, but for more irregular fields you can find counter-examples of non conservation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and hinting me to Onsager's conjecture which I was not aware of. However, I am not talking about the regularity of the field, which I called $\chi$, but the regularity of the mapping $\boldsymbol{\varphi}$. Obviously this regularity is violated already in frictionless flow  [link](https://youtu.be/Vs5gM7nSMBI?si=eCNbFRujElWinjEZ&t=65). 
So I think my question is very fundamental, why is it allowed to use RTT for non-smooth deformation mapps $\varphi$?

Comment: For Onsager's conjecture, it is the regularity of the velocity field that is relevant, $u$, which in your Lagrangian setting corresponds to $\partial_t\phi\circ \phi^{-1}$. Your $\chi$ rather corresponds to the specific energy $u^2$. This is why it is concrete example of the transport theorem not working due to the (spatial) irregularity of $u$, i.e. your $\phi$. To make it work outside the smooth setting, you'll need more sophisticated mathematical tools like Payley-Littlewood etc which is detailed in the linked article.